# How to add quotes to JSON value?

Tags: python, json, api

I am sending post API request and getting back a value:

```
first_post = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data_one),headers=headers)
first_response = first_post.json()
scroll_id = first_response['_scroll_id']
```

Then I am making a second API post request where I need to pass the scroll_id from the first response.

```
data_two = {
    "scroll": "5m",
    "scroll_id": scroll_id
}

second_post = requests.post(url_2,data=json.dumps(data_two),headers=headers)
second_response = second_post.json()
```

The problem is that the second post request is not working because of the sroll_id being 123abc instead of "123abc".

How would I add quotes to my data_two scroll_id value?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: probably `scroll_id` is an int so you can try with `str(scroll_id)`

Comment: "123abc" should just be "123abc" so if it doesnt work, you are having a number there.

Answer (score 0):

As per @rivamarco response having :

```
scroll_id = str(first_response['_scroll_id'])
```

Fixes the issue.